# How can GIMP's Blur Tool blur way more swiftly, effectually?

Tags: gimp, blur

Apprise me if you know better  [examples](https://www.dreamstime.com/photos-images/clear-boundary.html). I trust obvious what boundary I'm trying to Blur — the two different hues of grass or water. And the forehead with the bad haircut, because the hair cut off too abruptly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[xenoid advised](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/154189)

> If you want to use the blur tool: you can try to increase the "Force" in the Tool options and/or use a harder brush. You don't need to click hundreds of times, just depress the left mouse button and wiggle the mouse over the cut.

I tried this wiggling for the past ten minutes, but the boundary blurs too little and slowly! All this wiggling's WEARYING and FATIGUING my hand!!! I need the Blur tool to work more forcefully, expeditiously, nimbly!

1. What  if I increase the tool size to cover the whole borderline? Aim my mouse so that I cover the whole border. Then depress my mouse  and keeping it at the same spot, without any budging or wiggling?
2. Pls review my settings for the Blur tool? I turned up  Force to 100 as xenoid advised, but did I overlook anything else?

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?  As it stands, your question reads like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BillyKerr - for that, see comments under my answer. It *is* an XY Problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin - oh, I didn't see that. Thanks. Yeah, definitely an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overlooked the first 2 pieces of advice in the comments & in the answer. Why not use a blur filter, or a gradient instead?
The blur tool is just not designed to give you some huge 800px blend between 2 solid colours.
Pick a more suitable tool.

Just using a blown-up crop from your earlier question, so this is far more pixellated than using the original image…

5 minutes of scribbling with the blur tool
[image]

One tweak of a slider in Gaussian Blur
[image]

After the heavy question edit - I have absolutely no idea what the expected result for such as this could possibly be, but you can do the same thing with a feathered selected area…

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Very sorry...I wrote my post badly. I didn't mean that simple green vs. blue boundary. I meant borders in real life pictures. Pls see my edited post.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to blur the boundaries between distinct areas on the new examples? What do you hope to gain?

Comment: For my work, I need to combine pictures together and blur the boundaries. These examples are for practice.

Comment: You ***really*** need to ask the question you need the answer to - because this isn't the way I'd feather two images into each other to hide the join. If you ask the wrong question, you will get the wrong answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)